# Scatter plot with scalar data

Tags: matplotlib

I want to create a scatter plot with matplotlib where the data points have scalar data attached to them and are assigned a color depending on how large their attached value is relative to the other points in the set. I.e., I want something akin to a heatmap. However, I'm looking for a "discrete" heatmap, i.e. nothing should be ploted where there were no points in the original data set and, in particular, no interpolation (in space) should be performed.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 11):

you can use scatter, and set the attached value to c parameter:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl

x = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, 1000)
y = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, 1000)

z = np.sqrt(x*x+y*y)

pl.scatter(x, y, c=z)
pl.colorbar()
pl.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Solving this in Altair.

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl

x = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, 1000)
y = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, 1000)

z = np.sqrt(x*x+y*y)

df = pd.DataFrame({'x':x,'y':y, 'z':z})

from altair import *

Chart(df).mark_circle().encode(x='x',y='y', color='z')
```

[image]